# debounce function means e.preventDefault on mousewheel no longer working

Tags: javascript, debouncing

I am chaging the background of the page using mousewheel. I only want to trigger the mousewheel event once 1000ms, so for that I am using a debounce function.

Before I added the debounce function and used `e.preventDefault()` it prevented the scroll from working. However, now that I have added the debounce function this no longer works and the user can scroll the page again.

Please see code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',debounce(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //code to change the background image
    }, 1000))
});

function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

then build it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changeBackground = debounce(function(e){
        //code to change the background image
    }, 1000)
    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',debounce(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        changeBackground(e);
    })
});
```